# Convexity in single variable

Tags: matrices, optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, non-convex-optimization

I am trying to solve the below non-convex minimization problem

$$ \underset{X_1,x_2,X_3,\Lambda}{\mathrm{argmin}} \|A-X_1X_2\Lambda X_3 \|_F^2 $$

where $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$, $X_1 \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times k}$, $X_2 \in \mathbb{R}^{k \times k_1}$, $X_3 \in \mathbb{R}^{k_1 \times n}$, and $\Lambda \in \mathbb{R}^{k_1 \times k_1}_{+}$ is a diagonal matrix. $A$ is a known matrix. I am trying to check if the above problem is strongly convex in each variable or not. I am not able to figure out how to check if the problem will be strongly convex in each variable. Is it possible to find constraints on the variables such that the problem becomes strongly convex in each variable?

Attempt1: I can rewrite the above problem as $$ \underset{X,Y,Z}{\mathrm{argmin}} \|A-XYZ \|_F^2 $$ and I want to check if the above function is convex in $Y$ or not. Let $G = \|A-XYZ \|_F^2$ and I vectorize $Y$, then the hessian of vec($Y$) can be written as $X^TX \otimes Z^TZ$. I don't how to find conditions on $X$ and $Z$ such that the hessian of $Y$ is positive definite.

Comment: The function is separately convex in each variable.

Comment: Have you tried to show the the objective is convex in each variable?  What difficulty did you encounter?

Comment: @copper.hat I am not sure if the function is convex as hessian is dependent on other variables

Comment: @BrianBorchers Edited the question with my attempt.

Comment: @DushyantSahoo: I am sure, the convex function of an affine function is convex.

Comment: @BrianBorchers Oh yes, you are right, my bad. Actually, I was trying to search conditions on $X$ and $Z$ such that hessian $\succcurlyeq \mu I$ i.e. positive definitive where $\mu >0$, these conditions would make the function strongly convex in $Y$

Comment: It is simple to prove this function is not strictly convex in any individual variable. Consider for instance $X_1$—and suppose $X_2\Lambda X_3\equiv0$.

Comment: @MichaelGrant I was trying to find conditions on all variables such that the function becomes strongly convex in every variable, not the other way around.

Comment: I see. I doubt you will find them. Convexity is a very fragile property. It is an exception, not a rule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function cannot be strongly convex in each variable as the determinant of $X^TX \otimes Z^T Z$ is zero, the function is just convex.