# Condition for a matrix to be positive definite

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, positive-definite

I have $T = X^TX \otimes Z^TZ$ matrix where $X \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times k}$ and $Z \in \mathbb{R}^{k \times n}$. Is it possible to find conditions on $X$ and $Z$ such that $T \succeq \mu I$ in other words $T$ is a positive definite matrix?

Comment: You need $n=k$ and $X,Z$ has full rank for the $nk\times nk$ matrix $T$ to be positive-definite.

Comment: @user10354138 Can you please elaborate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Claim**: Suppose $A,B$ are square matrices.  Then $A\otimes B$ has full rank if and only if $A,B$ has full rank.

*Proof*: Follows immediately from $\det(A\otimes B)=\det(A)^m\det(B)^n$.  QED.

**Claim**: $X^TX\otimes Z^TZ=(X\otimes Z)^T(X\otimes Z)$ for any matrix $X,Z$ of any size.

*Proof*: Follows from the identities $(A\otimes B)(C\otimes D)=(AC)\otimes (BD)$ and $(A\otimes B)^T=A^T\otimes B^T$.  QED.

Let $X\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times k},Z\in\mathbb{R}^{k\times n}$.  Combining the two claims, $X^TX\otimes Z^TZ$ is positive semi-definite, and it is invertible iff both $X^TX$, $Z^TZ$ are invertible.  In other words, $X^TX\otimes Z^TZ$ is positive-definite iff $n=k$ and $X,Z$ are invertible.

Comment: If $k < n$, then the determinant of the $T$ is 0, right?

Comment: @DushyantSahoo Yes, the $n\times n$ matrix $Z^TZ$ will have rank $\leq k<n$.

Comment: How will the conditions change if I want to have $T$ matrix positive semi-definite? In this case $k<n$ condition won't be required. Actually, I am trying to solve  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3261399/convexity-in-single-variable pproblem.

Comment: then there are no conditions imposed.  $X^TX$ is psd for every real matrix $X$.